# Two density functions for the same distribution

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $p_1, p_2$ be two density functions for a stochastic variable $(X,Y)$. Assume that $p_1 = f^2$, where $f$ are the density functions of $X$ and $Y$, that is, $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed and independent.

Does it follow that $p_2 = f^2 = p_1$?

I have a theorem which allows me to conclude that it holds that $p_1 = p_2$ almost everywhere just by the fact that they give the same distribution, but now I wonder if it holds everywhere, since $p_2$ must also split into $f^2$?

Answer (score 1):

You still only have that $p_2 = p_1$ almost everywhere.

For instance, if $f$ is the density of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ (so that $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^2$), then you can define another function $g$ by $g(x) = 1$ for $x\in [0,1]\setminus\{1/2\}$, and $g(1/2) = 2$.

Then $g^2$ is still the density of $(X,Y)$. Even though $g^2$ is different from $f^2$, they are only different on the null set $[0,1]\times\{1/2\}\cup \{1/2\}\times [0,1]$, and the integrals of $f^2$ and of $g^2$ will still be equal.